# C++: How does set know when two items are equal?

Tags: c++, string, set

I have created a set of C-strings, supplying my own comparator function because I wanted it to only take take the first three characters into account. Here's its definition:

```
struct set_object {
 bool operator()(const char* first, const char* second) {
        return strncmp(first, second, 3) > 0;
 }
};
std::set<const char*, set_object> c_string_set;
```

It works as I wanted it to, sorting the strings as I add them the way I outlined in the set_object class. But the interesting part begins when I try to add a string that compares equal to one already added. For example, if I try to add "aaab" when there is already "aaa" in the set, it doesn't add it into the set. If I add "aaab" first, then try to add "aaa", it only lists "aaab". But how does it know when they are *equal* if I only provided a function that returns true when one of the strings is greater? It should return false when it's *either* equal or smaller!

To clarify, it's not a problem, just trying to figure out how C++ works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right that `set_object(x, y)` returning false doesn't say whether x is less than y or they are equal.  So set then calls `set_object(y, x)` to find out.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (!less(first,second) && !less(second,first)) // equivalent!
```

If neither one is less than the other, they are equivalent (not equal, there's a very subtle difference).

Answer (score 0):

If an item `x` is not greater nor smaller than another item `y`. it means that `x` and `y` are the same...

Answer (score 0):

The items are deemed *equivalent* if `a<b` and `b<a` are both `false`.

See http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html.

Comment: strictly speaking, its `a<b` and `b<a`.